# Stripe: Testing Webhook with manual object properties

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am testing stripe webhook `'customer.subscription.updated'` and it returns a subscription object in my listener `$subscription = $event->data->object;`.

I am sending the webhook by myself through the Stripe dashboard. My question is that can I make this webhook to send the subscription object properties according to my own will.

For example, it sends the status of subscription as 'active' but I want it to send the status as 'past_due' or 'canceled'.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can have it send `canceled` by [canceling the Subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/cancel).  The only way to have it be `past_due` is by using the `4000000000000341` [test card](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses) and then waiting for the payment to fail - and that's assuming your [automatic collection settings](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/automatic-collection#settings) are set up to transition to `past_due`.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to get the past_due status of a subscription by this event "customer.subscription.updated" during the subscription cycle.
Assume that payment is successful during subscription creation but failed during the subscription cycle.

Comment: You could do that by removing the Payment Method after the first successful invoice payment.